# Building a comment system in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a comment system for a custom CMS I'm building using Codeigniter. I thought it would be pretty simple to do, but I am stuck in a few spots.

Right now, I am using hidden fields to hold the Post ID and the Parent Comment ID. The Parent Comment ID is 0 if it's a standalone comment but changes to the Comment ID if it's a reply to a specific comment (so threaded comments). This was the only way I could come up with for the form to know what Post ID the comment was in reference to.

For the hidden fields I used the following validation: `trim|required|numeric`

I also have XSS Filtering and CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) Protection set to TRUE in my config. Is this enough to protect the form from being misused? Is there anything else I should be doing?

Should I be doing something else instead of the hidden fields?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you do deletions or updating the comments (via edit), check to see if the user_id updating the comment is the actual comment owner.  I'm assuming you have user_id in your comments table for a 1 to 1 relationship, i.e, a comment can have only one owner, the person who created the comment.

Maybe something like:

```
function is_comment_owner($comment_id, $user_id) {
    $this->db->where('comment_id', $comment_id);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->from('comments_table');
    if ($this->db->count_all_results() > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how paranoid you are / what your security requirements are.

The only problem I can foresee is if someone manually changes the parent ID to inject a comment on another post.  This might be a problem if you have different permission levels / only certain people are allowed to comment on certain sections.  You can get around it by doing some kind of reversible encryption on the IDs, but I wouldn't bother for most applications.

The `numeric` filter alone should prevent any xss problems.
As `user1062354` said, make sure you check permissions for editing and deleting on the server.